# Replace cell value in Google Script Apps

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to write a script that, when a cell in a sheet changes `"Негатив отсутствует"`, will replace the value of a cell in another sheet with the value `"Нерелевант"`. Help please, what did I do wrong?

```
function ChangeTone(event) { 
  if (event.source.getActiveRange().getValue()=="Негатив отсутствует" && event.source.getActiveSheet()=="Разметка ТОП100 по суду"){
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var currRow = sheet.getActiveCell().getRow();
    var value = sheet.getRange(currRow, 1).getDisplayValue();
    var pasteSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Тональность");
    var data = pasteSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
//    if(currRow > 2){
//      sheet.deleteRow(currRow);
//    }
    for(var i = 1; i<data.length;i++){
          if(data[i][1] == value){
            pasteSheet.getRange((i), 2).clear({contentsOnly: true});
            pasteSheet.getRange((i), 2).setValue('Нерелевант');
            break;
          }
  };
//    sheet.getActiveCell().setValue("");
    
    
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Explanation / Issues:

**Issue:**

There is a clear issue with your code and in particular here:

`event.source.getActiveSheet()=="Разметка ТОП100 по суду"`

You are comparing a [sheet object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet) with a string and this will always return `false`. The correct way to do it would be:

`event.source.getActiveSheet().getName()=="Разметка ТОП100 по суду"`

but here I also tried to optimize your code because it is quite inefficient.

**Optimization:**

You don't take full advantage of the [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events).

- `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()` can be replaced by `e.source`.

You also define the same variables multiple times when you only need to do that once:

- For `event.source.getActiveSheet()` and `var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();` you can define a single variable to store the active sheet object and call it whenever you need it.

Last but not least. I am not quite sure about your logic regarding the `for` loop since you haven't mentioned it in your question.

But I see you use a `for` loop, an `if` statement and a `break` line to escape the `for` loop as soon as there is a match between the source value and the value in the paste sheet.

- Instead of using a `for` loop, you can use [findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) to find the value that matches the criterion `data[i][1] == value`.
- Also the full `getDataRange()` is not needed if you intend to use only one column, therefore I change that part too.

### Solution:

```
function onEdit(e){
 const ss = e.source;
 const ar = e.range;
 const activeSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
 const pasteSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Тональность");
  if (ar.getValue()=="Негатив отсутствует" && activeSheet.getName()=="Разметка ТОП100 по суду"){
    const value = activeSheet.getRange(ar.getRow(), 1).getValue();
    const data = pasteSheet.getRange('B1:B'+pasteSheet.getLastRow()).getValues().flat();
    const indx = data.findIndex((element) => element == value);
    if (indx>-1){
      const pasteRng = pasteSheet.getRange(indx+1,2);
      pasteRng.clearContent();
      pasteRng.setValue('Нерелевант');   
  }
  }
}
```

Let me know if that worked for you, otherwise I would like to modify it so it does.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much! The script works =)
I also made a working script before. But this is my first script, so it is much slower and not so ... concise. Also it was fired with a trigger, and yours works as a simple event.
My old version:

```
function ChangeTone(event) { 
  if (event.source.getActiveRange().getValue()=="Негатив отсутствует" && event.source.getActiveSheet().getName() == "Разметка ТОП100 СУД"){
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var currRow = sheet.getActiveCell().getRow();
    sheet.getRange("A"+currRow+":F"+currRow).setBackground('#ff5a5a');
    var value = sheet.getRange(currRow, 1).getDisplayValue();
    var pasteSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Тональность");
    var data = pasteSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
    for(var i = 1; i<data.length;i++){
          if(data[i][0] == value){
           pasteSheet.getRange((i+1), 2).setValue('Нерелевант');
           sheet.getRange("C"+currRow+":F"+currRow).deleteCells(SpreadsheetApp.Dimension.ROWS);
          }          
  };
    sheet.getRange("A"+currRow+":B"+currRow).setBackground('#ffffff'); 
}
}
```

So took your code and added row deletion after replacing cell value. Final version:

```
function onEdit(e){
 const ss = e.source;
 const ar = e.range;
 const arRow = ar.getRow();
 const activeSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
 const pasteSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Тональность");
  if (ar.getValue()=="Негатив отсутствует" && activeSheet.getName()=="Разметка ТОП100 СУД"){
    const value = activeSheet.getRange(arRow, 1).getValue();
    const data = pasteSheet.getRange('A1:A'+pasteSheet.getLastRow()).getValues().flat();
    const indx = data.findIndex((element) => element == value);
    if (indx>-1){
      const pasteRng = pasteSheet.getRange(indx+1,2);
      pasteRng.clearContent();
      pasteRng.setValue('Нерелевант');
      activeSheet.getRange("C"+arRow+":F"+arRow).deleteCells(SpreadsheetApp.Dimension.ROWS);
  }
  }
}
```

Thanks again for your help =)